# Get email value from SweetAlert2 to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert2

Good day, what's the best way to implement PHP into Javscript, I need to do some coding stuff after email is entered

```
swal({
  type: "success",
  title: "Congrats!",
  text: "Please enter your PayPal email address.",
  input: "email",
  buttonsStyling: false,
  heightAuto: false,
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  allowEscapeKey: false
}).then(function (email) {
  swal({
  type: "success",
  text: "You will get your reward within 48 hours.",
  buttonsStyling: false,
  heightAuto: false,
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  allowEscapeKey: false
  })
})
```

. `<?php ?>` Wouldn't work i guess ? how can i get entered value to use it in php ?

Answer (score 2):

`php` is strictly a server-side language, thus it won't work on the client-side (where JavaScript runs).

In order to communicate between the client and server side, I suggest using AJAX.

For example, when a user types their email and submit, it can trigger ajax request to the server (php) and do further action and get a response as well.

There are a lot (I mean, A LOT) of tutorials on Google how to achieve it.

I suggest you start with "send ajax to php" and go from there.

Based on the server setting you have, you will be able to figure it out fairly quickly.

To give you an idea, following is a sample AJAX call in JS:

```
 function sample_AJAX(a, b, c) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax_url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: a,
            id: b
        },
        success: c
    });
};
```

Good luck!

Comment: Make sure to accept it as an answer so others can see it too. Thanks!